# cocos 2d-x add touch event callback error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x scene and Button on it. 
i try to add touch event listener add provide it with callback function:

```
preloadScene.h:

...
public:
virtual void Do(Touch* touch, Event* event);
...

preloadScene.cpp

bool Preload::init(){
...
auto button = ui::Button::create("assets/preload_button.png");
...
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(Preload::Do, this);
button->addTouchEventListener(listener);
...
}
```

During compilation i got this error:
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

i understand that something wrong with callback or the way i use it. Please help.

P.S: Next lines work just fine, but i want to have this event-handling code encapsulated in other function.

```
*button->addTouchEventListener(
    [](Ref* sender, ui::Widget::TouchEventType type) {
    switch (type) {
    case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN: {
        CCLOG("touch began");
        auto scene = MainMenu::createScene();
        Director::getInstance()->popScene();
        Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
    }
        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: use lambda to call your function.

```
button->addTouchEventListener([this](Touch*, Event*){ this->Do();}
```

`CC_CALLBACK_2` uses `std::bind` under the hood. The declaration of `Button::addTouchEventListener` is `void Button::addTouchEventListener(const ccWidgetTouchCallback& callback)`, where  `ccWidgetTouchCallback` is `std::function<void(Ref*,Widget::TouchEventType)>` rather than a `EventTouchListener`.
 It is a bad practice to bind a virtual function, since the derived version will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
button->addClickEventListener([=](Ref*)
{
  Do();
});
```

Comment: That seems the most easy way to do this.